# Tangential component of the "electric" vector spherical harmonic $N_{lm} = \nabla \times (h X_{lm})$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, spherical-harmonics

So I want to solve the problem of an electromagnetic plane wave scattering by a sphere myself, and one of the crucial steps is to solve the scattering of a converging TE- or TM-polarized vector spherical harmonic (VSH) by the sphere. To that end, I expand the field outside and inside the sphere  into a set of TE and TM-polarized VSHs. I'm going to follow Jackson's Classical electrodynamics with his $\mathbf X_{lm}$ angular functions.
The TE polarized part (E is normal to the radius vector) of the field takes the form:
$$
E = \begin{cases} 
h^{(2)}_\ell \mathbf X_{\ell m} + r h^{(1)}_\ell \mathbf X_{\ell m}, & r > R \newline
t h^{(2)}_\ell \mathbf X_{\ell m}, & r < R
\end{cases}
$$
where h^1,2 are spherical Hankel function representing outgoing and incoming harmonics, and $r$ and $t$ are the unknown reflection and transmission amplitudes.
Magnetic field of TE-polarized part is:
$$
H = \begin{cases} 
\frac{i}{k_1} \nabla \times [h^{(2)}_\ell \mathbf X_{\ell m}] + \frac{i}{k_1} r \nabla \times [ h^{(1)}_\ell \mathbf X_{\ell m}], & r > R \newline
\frac{i}{k_2} t \nabla \times [ h^{(2)}_\ell \mathbf X_{\ell m}], & r < R
\end{cases}
$$
(I might have missed a minus in the above, doesn't matter)

Now I need to impose continuity of tangential components of E and H at the interface, $r = R$.
Since $\mathbf X_{lm}$ are normal to the radius vector, continuity of the electric field is easy. But the tang component of H is $\hat{\mathbf n} \times H$, which gives me $\hat{\mathbf n} \times \nabla \times [ h^{(1,2)} _\ell\mathbf X_{\ell m}]$. How do I calculate these bloody cross products and satisfy their continuity?

PS $h^2 _\ell$ inside the sphere should of course be replaced $j_\ell$ to ensure the field is finite in the origin, but that's not the point.